# QCCompositionPickerPanel Preview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsview

I'm having a problem with my OS X app. Basically I have a `NSView` with several `QCViews` on it. In each `QCView` I load a composition file (`Composition.qtz`). If I want to load a filter from `QCCompositionPickerPanel` which looks like this: [[image: !QCComposition Picker Panel]

I get a strange error in log. Beside this, the the `QCCompositionPickerPanel` does not look good without "previews" like the bottom left image.

Here is the log:

```
2016-06-14 19:45:28.747 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** QCPlugIn: Cannot preflight plug-in at path "/Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin" (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3587 "dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ImageExporter): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ImageExporter: file too short" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle is damaged or missing necessary resources., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSFilePath=/Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ImageExporter, NSDebugDescription=dlopen_preflight(/Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ImageExporter): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin/Contents/MacOS/ImageExporter: file too short, NSBundlePath=/Users/xxx/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Plug-Ins/ImageExporter.plugin, NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “ImageExporter” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources.})
2016-06-14 19:45:32.325 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** <QCNodeManager | namespace = "com.apple.QuartzComposer" | 382 nodes>: Patch with name "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer" is missing
2016-06-14 19:45:32.326 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x112e3ce10 "(null)">:
Cannot create node of class "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer" and identifier "(null)"
2016-06-14 19:45:32.326 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x112e3ce10 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["output" @ "Splitter_7"] to ["inputPath" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.326 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x112e3ce10 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["outputTime" @ "Clock_1"] to ["_time" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.326 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x112e3ce10 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["outputImage" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"] to ["source_0" @ "Multiplexer_4"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.328 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** State restoration failed on <QCPatch = 0x112e3ce10 "(null)">
2016-06-14 19:45:32.342 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** <QCNodeManager | namespace = "com.apple.QuartzComposer" | 382 nodes>: Patch with name "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer" is missing
2016-06-14 19:45:32.342 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x1007212f0 "(null)">:
Cannot create node of class "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer" and identifier "(null)"
2016-06-14 19:45:32.343 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x1007212f0 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["output" @ "Splitter_7"] to ["inputPath" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.343 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x1007212f0 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["outputTime" @ "Clock_1"] to ["_time" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.343 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** Message from <QCPatch = 0x1007212f0 "(null)">:
Cannot create connection from ["outputImage" @ "BackdropsQCQuickTimePlayer_1"] to ["source_0" @ "Multiplexer_4"]
2016-06-14 19:45:32.345 Selfie Collage[968:643738] *** State restoration failed on <QCPatch = 0x1007212f0 "(null)">
```

Can anyone help me please?
I can provide pieces of code if it`s necessary.

Comment: look at these threads : http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartzcomposer-dev/2014/Mar/msg00034.html

Comment: Thank you @StefanSzekeres I found them to, but does not help me....